# WCF throws System.ServiceModel.FaultException: Access is Denied

Tags: vb.net, wcf

im new to consuming wcf services, so here i got a console app which i added a service reference.

When i run the code, its giving me the FaulException: Access is denied.
Below is the stack trace.

[image]

Now in my endpoint i have the address node of https://addresshere/Soap11 (its auto populated when i add service reference),
I was wondering if Soap11 is really included in there or just up until the svc.

Any hints/help with where to check for the problem is much appreciated. 
I apologies if this seems to be a vague question but any information i can share, just ask for it in the comment section.

Thank you all.

Comment: do you have access to the wcf service?, can yiou change its webconfig?

Comment: unfortunately i dont have access to it, can you enlighten me on what seems to be the problem ?

Comment: When I had this issue, it was a message security issue, it could be a lot of things

Comment: is this a framework generated exception or an exception that is being returned by the service's method ?

Comment: Its an exception generated by the service.

Comment: may i know how you solved this, ill atleast try to look at it